# What does %#ok<SAGROW> comment mean in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, comments

I've encountered many MATLAB codes which have a `%#ok<SAGROW>` comments. This comment is used  in different circumstances and I can't figure it out what it means.

As an example:

```
i = 1; 
flag = true;
for l = 1:k
    while(flag==true)
        if(probs(i)~=0)
            leaves(l).val = i-1; %#ok<*SAGROW>
            leaves(l).zero = '';
            leaves(l).one = '';
            leaves(l).prob = probs(i);
            i = i + 1; 
            flag = false;
        else
            i = i+1;
            flag = true;
        end
    end
flag =true;
end
```

There are other references to this comment too, for instace:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/151765/answer.aspx
- http://www.scribd.com/doc/69869075/EEE-554-Matlab-Solutions
- http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/321047
- http://www.nd.edu/~jrunkle1/ballis_problem.m

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It suppresses `mlint` warnings. In this specific case, it is about not pre-allocating an array.

[mlint](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/brqxeeu-151.html#brqxeeu-156) is one of the static code analysis tools that Matlab has. It finds possible errors and shows warnings.

**Edit(1)**: 
I've just noticed that your question is about `SAGROW`, not `AGROW`. I could not find it. My guess is that it is an old/new mlint syntax.

Answer (score 6):

[General answer](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/check-code-for-errors-and-warnings.html#brx2q1o) (for different values in the angle brackets):

Type `msgid:SAGROW` in Preferences -> Code Analyzer.

For others `msgid:<your-ok-msg-id>`.

**edit:**
shortest way, 1. remove the comment, 2. read the codeanalyzer tooltip of the underline piece of code.

Comment: How do you do the reverse?

Comment: @Eric Right-click on the words with the red underline, and choose "Supress [warning-magssage]..."->"On this line" will give you the proper code for supressing this warning.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about `SAGROW`, but `AGROW` would mean that a given array/vector/matrix `<name> might be growing inside a loop. Consider preallocating for speed`.

Comment: Does `AGROW` tell the MATLAB to pre-allocate the array/matrix to increase the performance, or it just suppress the pre-allocation warning?